# 'Nested arrays are not supported' FireStore Swift iOS

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to upload complex nested arrays into Firestore by Google, however when I set my array, I am getting the following issue:

"'Nested arrays are not supported'"

I am attempting to do this for iOS/Swift. Is there a work around to this?

I have around 10 arrays I need to upload, which vary in nested size, the greatest being like so:

```
var array : [[[[String]]]] =  [[[[String()]]]]
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While Firestore supports arrays, it usually not the optimal way to store your data. It makes it incredibly difficult to get back sub-levels of data. Also, burying data multiple levels deep is not a strong suit of NoSQL databases. [Denormalizing](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) your data is best practice in many cases. Firestore does a great job of insulting developers from that but it's still a 'thing'. Perhaps if you can provide some additional info, like example data or what you're trying to do we can suggest a better solution.

Comment: Hello Jay, Thank you for responding, My data varies in the information that is in it, I am sorting through the data myself within the app, as I am reading CSV files and storing them within an array and sorting from there, I just don't want to have to upload the content of the CSV file to an array and resort to having to re-sort the information into arrays, as I have my made arrays upon reading the CSV file, I dont need firebase itself to sort through the information for me, I just need a place to store the arrays, as I am sorting them myself.

Comment: lol. Wait. no. Firebase does not insult developers. Well, not usually anyway ;-). That should be *insulate* developers.

Comment: Any Suggestions On What I could do as alternative? @jay

Comment: As you see, arrays can't really be nested like that in Firestore. One solution is to store references to other arrays inside an array, and inside those arrays store references to those arrays. childArray0 = [a,b,c] and childArray1 = [d,e,f] and then parentArray = [ childArray0, childArray1 ]. Essentially the arrays would be stored 'flat' and you would keep references to them within collections and documents..... next comment

Comment: However, another avenue is to convert your Array to a Data object (as perhaps store as a string). It's been awhile but something like *let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: myArray, requiringSecureCoding: false)* and then when reading it back *if let thisArray = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data)*

Comment: Thanks Jay, this worked! I used the later option!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jay's help, I was able to have a work around, by saving my array as a Data Object, like so:

```
var ARRAYNAME : [[String]] = [[String()]]
do {
         let tempArrayData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.ARRAYNAME, requiringSecureCoding: false)
        }catch{}
```

Then to read it, I did as follow:

```
do { let thisArray = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(tempArrayData) }catch{}

for info in thisArray! as! [[String]] {
    print(info)
}
```